# Plateform to manage push notifications with PhoneGap

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification

I used Cordova PushNotification Plugin to add push notifications to my PhoneGap app ([this](https://github.com/mgcrea/cordova-push-notification) plugin). It worked when I used a simple php script with a particular device token to push a notification (with [this](http://d1xzuxjlafny7l.cloudfront.net/downloads/SimplePush.zip) script).

I did this for one device, but I know it's a little bit different when it comes to multiple devices. So, is there any plateform that allows a user to manage push notifications (like https://parse.com/products/push) ?

Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's a platform that's perfect for what you want: [pushwoosh](http://www.pushwoosh.com/). You can easily add it to Phonegap.

**EDIT for more information for iOS you can search here:

- [iphone configuration guide](http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/iphone-configuration-guide/)
- [SDK integration](http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/iphone-push-notification-sdk-configuration-guide/)

These are the steps you must do:

1. First you must register in Google APIs site, select Services: https://code.google.com/apis/console/
2. Turn the Google Cloud Messaging toggle to ON
3. In the Terms of Service page, accept the terms.Now you need to create the Server Key
4. Press “API Access” button
5. Press “Create new Server key”. Either a server key or a browser key should work. The advantage to using a server key is that it allows you to whitelist IP addresses.
6. Press “Create”.
7. You can find your `GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID` from the URL in your Google API console. Usually it looks like this: https://code.google.com/apis/console/#project:12345678912:access In this example, it would be: 12345678912
8. Enter in Pushwoosh copanel: https://cp.pushwoosh.com/
9. Create or enter in `My Apps` menu
10. When you enter into an app you'll see the Application code in that page or in the navigator's url and this will be your `PUSHWOOSH_APP_ID`
11. Download de SDK and insert it in your project.
12. Change the pushnofitication.js to point to your project ID and Pushwoosh app.

Comment: BTW you don't have to look for the GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID in the URL anymore - now Pushwoosh guide relates to the PROJECT NUMBER, because there's another thing called "Project ID" in the Google Console, which was a bit confusing. Take a look at the latest [Android  API Configuration guide](http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/enabling-gcm-services-for-google-api/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @mram888. It's very useful :) But, what if I want to do the same thing with iOS ? Is Pushwoosh still works ?

Comment: Yes, Pushwoosh works for: Android, iOS,BlackBerry, Mac, Phonegap,Windows Phone, Nokia,...